# Список воспроизведений Qt

Tags: c++, qt, видео

Подскажите при помощи каких виджетов в Qt можно создать нечто похожее на список рекомендованных видео на youtube.com. Это будет список воспроизведений, в который пользователь сам добавляет видео, при нажатии на определенное, оно воспроизведется. Возможно QListWidget, но как добавить действие при нажатии на видео, как определить на какое именно выбрано и самое главное, можно ли добавить туда QVideoWidget.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, `QListWidget` подойдёт для этой цели.

Скорее всего Вам понадобится также делегат, напр., `QStyledItemDelegate`, в которм и можно будет отлавливать нажатие на определённую иконку видео. Для этого, в классе делегата надо переопределить метод `editorEvent()`, что-то в этом роде:

```
bool Delegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease){
        if (/* в районе вашей видио иконки */)
            emit this->clickedVideo(index);
    }
}
```

Как ваше видео иконка располагается, можно определить в методе `paint()` делегата. Либо оставить по умолчанию.

Сигнал `clickedVideo(index)` соединяете со слотом, который будет проигрывать видео. Переменная `index` Вам поможет определить на каком видео был сделан click.

Про добавлении `QVideoWidget`, не совсем понятно, куда именно Вы хотите. Если вы хотите чтоб видео проигрывалось прямо в `QListWidget`, то тогда надо искать как это сделать в делегате, в методе `paint()`.

Если Вы хотите, чтобы каждое видео было представленно иконкой, но само видео открывалось в главном окне (или другом виджете), то тогда будет просто достаточно установить размер video иконок для `ListWidget`:

```
listWidget->setIconSize(200,200);
```

Потом останется только соединить сигналы и слоты для достижение  желаемого результата. Более подробый ответ дать довольно сложно, т.к. вопрос содержит несколько вопросов. Советую почитать про делегаты и просмотреть примеры как их использовать. Надеюсь, это Вам поможет найти решение.